# Can I change a private methods visibility in order to unit test them

Tags: vba, unit-testing, tdd, rubberduck

I see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34658/5996109) answer that for Java you can set the visibility of a private method to "true" in a unit test in order to test the method. Is there something like this available for VBA, so that I can unit test private methods using RD-VBA?

If not, and I have a class that works out some logic in three private methods and give it back to a return value, am I doomed to only give a input value and test the return value, without being able to test the three private methods doing the heave lifting in between?

Comment: I know you can execute private methods residing in normal modules via the `Application.OnTime` command. I'm not sure if that'd work for class modules - or if that would be a sensible thing to do. For reasons why you should not do what you intend to do, watch *[TDD - where did it all go wrong?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZ05e7EMOLM)* by Ian Cooper which I found highly enlightening and agreeable.

Comment: @Inario, I forgot to leave a comment to say what a great recommendation your video was. I loved every minute of it and it did indeed enlighten me a lot about the whole subject. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't *need* to write tests for private methods, regardless of the language. You test your public API, what's private is implementation detail that isn't relevant.

If it *is* relevant and important enough to be tested on its own, then you should extract that private method to another class, and expose it as a public member of that class.

For example once I had a form and I wanted to limit user input in a textbox to numeric characters, and since I'm reusing that logic elsewhere then instead of treating it as an implementation detail of my form, I extracted a `AsciiInputValidator` class, and its public `IsValidNumericValue` method could be tested in every possible way as its own SUT.

Don't test private methods: the public ones invoke them anyway.

Unfortunately the [Extract Class](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/892) refactoring feature is not implemented as of this writing, so for now Rubberduck can't do this automatically for you... but it's definitely in-scope and if you're reading this and you're up for a bit of a C# metaprogramming challenge, go for it, pull requests are always welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a public wrapper like

```
public sub testPrivateSub(param1,param2...)
     PrivateSub(param1,param2....)
end sub

private sub PrivateSub(param1,param2....)
....
end sub
```